# SED in remote SUDO ssh script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sed, remote-access

I am trying to disable RHN check when running yum on 1000 servers. It is done by:

Editing this file `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/rhnplugin.conf`

```
[main]
enabled = 0
```

I wrote a script to do this remotely. We are using individual accounts and I need to execute this command using SUDO:

```
for HOST in $(cat serverlist ) ; do echo $HOST; ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $HOST -t 'sudo cp /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/rhnplugin.conf /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/rhnplugin.$(date +%F) ; sudo sed -i -e "s/1/0/g" /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/rhnplugin.conf ' ; done
```

I know it is a long line but why does it not work?

All individual commands work on their own

```
sudo cp /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/rhnplugin.conf /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/rhnplugin.$(date +%F)

sudo sed -i -e "s/1/0/g" /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/rhnplugin.conf
```

have tried escaping the special chars:

```
sudo sed -i -e "s\/1\/0\/g" /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/rhnplugin.conf
```

But I get an error all the time:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `?'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try checking the actual sudo command executed on the remote host from `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log` file.

Comment: Any reason why you do not rely on configuration management software? You can do that very easily and consistently with [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/)

Comment: please also specify what you mean by "it does not work". If you're getting error messages, please add them to your question. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The sudo(1) command expects a pseudo-teletype (pty) and fails if it does not see one.  Rewrite your command line to use su(1) instead.  Use your local sudo(1) configuration to limit access to this script so only the select few can execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer to this question, or rather workaround. See the snippet below, where I got to -as root- ssh as *me* (szymonri) to other host, then invoke sed command as root in order to edit `/etc/hosts` file. All thanks to `base64` magic.

```
ME=`echo -e "$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')\toverlord"`
B64ENC=`echo "sed -i 's/.*overlord/$ME/g' /etc/hosts" | base64`
su - szymonri sh -c "ssh jetson bash -c \\\"echo $B64ENC \| base64 --decode \| sudo bash \\\""
```

1. line: I"m obtaining m yown IP address as an `/etc/hosts` line
2. line: I'm base64 encoding sed command with the first line in it.
3. line: I'm invoking the SSH shenannigan, where I su as regular user, ssh to another box as the user, and use power of sudo to edit the file.